# Virtual Machine Ubuntu 20.04 LTS : connect: Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

I am new to linux and networking and today I have a "connect: Network is unreachable" when executing `ping` or `sudo apt` commands. I have seen some similar questions but still don't have a clue about how to fix it.

My ubuntu system is installled on my machine by VMware.

messages I got after running `sudo lshw -C network`

```
    *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:c3:23:09
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`ip a`

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:c3:23:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Anyone can help me with it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem after moving my ubuntu vm to a different host. The following steps worked for me, the reloading of the kernel modules might not be required, cannot reproduce as it is working now. I guess the network-manager is broken.

- unload /reload the kernel modules
- list the network adapters to get the name of the device (in my case it was „ens33“)
- get an ip for the device
- do an apt-get update / upgrade
- reinstall network-manager

```
sudo rmmod e1000
sudo rmmod e1000e
sudo rmmod igb

sudo modprobe e1000
sudo modprobe e1000e
sudo modprobe igb

sudo dhclient ens33

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: magic! this works for me too, installed ubuntu in vmware16 , but networking didn't work, until these steps.

Comment: Work for me as well!

Comment: Does not work in my case!!! I can ping using ip4 address but not ip6 e.g. when I run ping -I ens33 fe80::20c:29ff:fe85:ccce I get ping: unknown iface ens33

Comment: @Ibraheem maybe ens33 is not the correct interface name (unknown iface ens33)? just run 'ip a' to check the name

Comment: The answer for me was `sudo dhclient ens33`.  Thank you.

Comment: magic command is - `sudo dhclient ens33` Thanks a lot, You made my day :)

Comment: It worked for me too. Great answer after searching alot and doing multiple experiments that did not work.